# Looking for a Catholic Arabic bible

Tags: catholicism, bible-translation, resource-request, deuterocanonical-books

I'm trying to track down an Arabic bible which contains all the books, rather than the 66 book protestant canon.

I'm finding this hard to do. There are many Arabic translations out there but often it isn't clear whether they contain the deuterocanonicals or not.

Please guide me to a Catholic Arabic translation? Ideally purchasable online in Hardcover.

(The Sharif bible keeps coming across my radar and looks appealing and affordable: does it contain all the books?)

Comment: Have you tried [searching WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=catholic+bible&fq=ln%3Aara&qt=sort&se=yr&sd=desc&qt=sort_yr_desc)?

Comment: If there is a Maronite Rite Church near by, you may be able to ask the Pastor as they use Arabic in their liturgy.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are several Bibles in Arabic available online at [www.archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=bible%20arabic&and[]=mediatype%3A%22texts%22). As I do not know Arabic, you might need to check whether they include the Deuterocanonical books or not.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_Arabic#Later_Christian_translations), there has been three versions of the bible in Arabic done by Catholics. The first one, in 1671, published in Rome. I doubt this is sold online anywhere.

The second was done by the Jesuits of Lebanon/Beirut in 1880. A reprint was made later on. The publisher's website is [here](http://www.darelmachreq.com/en). But actually, you can buy that bible from the Bible Society in Lebanon, [here](https://shop.biblesociety.org.lb/bibles/arabic-bibles/jesuit-arabic-bibles.html) (source of this suggestion [here](https://forums.catholic.com/t/are-there-any-catholic-bibles-in-arabic/140516/5)).

Finally, albeit not Catholic, the Bible Society published in 1992 the "Today's Arabic Version with Deuterocanonicals". Some shops that sell it are listed [here](http://www.mliles.com/melkite/arabicbible.shtml) (albeit the page is old).  It might be the same as [this one](https://www.bibles.com/arabic-bible-today-s-arabic-version.html), but you might want to ask.

I am surprised of the very few translations available!

Comment: Maybe because the majority of Arabs are Muslims so not much translations available.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are quite a few Catholic and Orthodox translations around. You may find them in Lebanese bookstores, e.g.:

[Librairie Antoine](https://www.antoineonline.com/listing.aspx?q=bible%20arabic&type=0)

[Ayat](https://ayatonline.com/58-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B3)

You can easily find them in Catholic bookstores in Lebanon, too.